# Cheap RAID 5 controller for Dell T7500 to use 3 500GB drives over 4 500GB drives in RAID 10

Tags: data-storage, raid-controller, raid

I currently have a Dell T7500.  The onboard RAID card can do RAID 0, 1, 10.  I would like to create a 1TB partition that has redundancy out of SSD's.  Currently I would be able to use 2 1 TB with RAID 0, or 4 500GB with RAID 10.

In order to save cost, I was thinking I could use RAID 5 with 3 500GB drives.

Is there a hardware RAID card that I could use that would allow me to use only 3 500GB drives?  The cost would have to be less than the 4th drive or it would not be economical to do.

Extras such as future expansion would also be nice.

.

Budget: 500GB drives are about $150. So between $100 and $200

For the connection type, PCI would be the standard. Having 4 SATA ports would be the most likely method of connection to the drives